# How to redirect page after "Enable Unsafe Scripts" is enabled?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website that requires "Load Unsafe Scripts" to be enabled to load. What I want is the site to redirect to another after the user enables the "Load Unsafe Scripts" option is enabled. I can work with HTML, and JavaScript. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should fix your site to not be insecure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, you really should focus on fixing the unsafe script by serving everything (or nothing) from HTTPS.

If you absolutely can't for some reason, and for the sake of exercise: there is no trigger that you can directly react to when this occurs.

Your only real option would be to periodically try to add the script again if it hasn't been already. This wouldn't involve a redirect, but just pulling the script(s) in again.

Something like this:

```
function loadUnsafe() {
  if (!somethingInYourScript) {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://path.to/my-script.js';
    document.appendChild(script);
    setTimeout(loadUnsafe, 10000); // wait 10 seconds to try again
  }
}

loadUnsafe();
```

This will try to pull in your script every 10 seconds if `somethingInYourScript` doesn't exist. Once it does exist, it'll stop.

The `somethingInYourScript` would be something that the script pulls in (for example, if you were trying to bring in jQuery, you could check if `jQuery` variable exists because it will once the script is loaded.

You could try to pull in the main file you want (if your site can handle that), or you could try to pull in an unsafe script that would cause a redirect/refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can load a script from an unsave source which redirect to the other page.
Something like

```
var locationn = "https://google.com";
window.location = locationn;
```

But you realy need to make your scripts save...